# Find all 'public void' methods not annotated with '@Test'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to perform structural search on my tests to detect all methods that look like tests but are not annotated with `@Test`.

I tried with this pattern with no success (no matching code found):

```
@$Annotation$ public void $method$()

$Annotation$ - text like: ^Test$, min occurs: 0, max occurs: 0
$method$ - text like: should|test, min occurs: 1, max occurs: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, you have to try to provide a class with your pattern too, as it's done in templates:

```
class $Class$ {
  @$Annotation$( )
  $MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$);
}
```

Furthermore, you have to change the `$method$` variable to something like `should.*|test.*` to accept not a whole words only.

I've tested it with IntelliJ Idea 15, it's working for the methods like:

```
public void testSomething() {

}

public void shouldSomething() {

}
```

only if the `$Class$` is provided in search template and the method names regexes contain `.*` to match any method, which name begins with `test` or `should`.

Comment: Method patterns without surrounding class will be possible in the next version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I had to replace `$MethodType$` with `public void` as it was matching also `private` methods

Comment: @MichalKordas you're welcome. Yes, I just inserted this one as an example, how it's done by default. While tested it, I used the same pattern, as you provided, but with the class

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the *Old style JUnit test method in JUnit 4 class* inspection. This inspection detects methods that look like tests, but are not annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, as majority of my test cases starts with `should` instead of `test`.